# PDF media query being ignored

Tags: css, pdf, printing, media-queries

i want to generate a pdf from a browser using a css @media rule. i need this pdf in a specific size so i tried this:

**CSS**

```
@media print {

@page {
    size: 150mm 150mm !important;
    }

    }
```

However, the browsers i tried (FF, chrome, safari) ignored and/or overruled this code and keep creating a A4-size pdf. Tried to change settings in the printer dialog with no result. Does anyone has experience with this?

Happy with any suggestions! -j

Comment: What are you using to create the PDF?

Comment: just by saving the webpage i am working on as a pdf in the printer dialog - looked but didn't find an alternative yet